# Oracle APEX - Value of Shuttle in Modal Page not available

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Oracle APEX 18.1 : 
I got a shuttle in a modal page.
If I want to get the value of this shuttle I normally go to the dev console of chrome and type e.g. `$v("Px_SHUTTLE");`

This all works fine within **normal pages** but when I implement a shuttle in a **modal page** I can't see the selected items from the shuttle with `$v`.

Is this normal or a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred method for this would be to use

```
apex.item("Px_SHUTTLE").getValue();
```

But your method should work too. I tried them both on Apex 5.1 and they work. I tried them also on 18.1 and they don't work. This appears to be a bug because it's not mentioned in the [changelog](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#HTMRN-GUID-0F34A43F-A2B7-4D06-AA39-839396676C26) of Apex 18.1.

Keep an eye out on the [Known Issues](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/apex181-known-issues-4478237.html) to see if there is going to be a patch for it soon.